# AVG with OVER - invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have what I believe to be a correctly written sql query that calculates the average using an over clause to window the results. However, I'm getting an error when I include the over clause.

```
SELECT date,
        Day_Name_of_week,
        AVG(SalesItems_Breakfast) OVER (PARTITION BY Day_Name_of_week) AS BreakfastAvg
    FROM day_Sales_total
    GROUP BY date, day_Sales_total.Day_Name_of_week
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 93
>   Column 'day_Sales_total.SalesItems_Breakfast' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Which is bizarre, because as SalesItems_Breakfast is inside the AVG function.

However, the below query runs fine, the only difference being the over clause has been removed:

```
SELECT date,
        Day_Name_of_week,
        AVG(SalesItems_Breakfast) AS a --OVER (PARTITION BY Day_Name_of_week) AS BreakfastAvg
    FROM day_Sales_total
    GROUP BY date, day_Sales_total.Day_Name_of_week
```

What's going on?

Comment: By adding a `PARTITION BY` you're creating a further sub-grouping of results, so the `AVG` value then has to be included in the `GROUP BY` since it is a separate grouping in the result set. I'd suggest reading the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) for a better understanding of the function.

Comment: You do not need a window function  for this simple aggregation - simply drop the `OVER` clause, because it partitions by the same criteria as that of your grouping.

Comment: @mustaccio no. The `group by` is by 2 columns,. The `partition by` is by one of them only.

Comment: Yeah, the window clause was unnecessary, yesterday was a long day, I clearly had lost my ability to write sql!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove the group by clause or apply the avg function without an window or as someone else suggested, add an extra aggregate function that satisfies the group by clause:

a)

```
SELECT date, Day_Name_of_week
     , AVG(SalesItems_Breakfast) OVER (PARTITION BY Day_Name_of_week) 
           AS BreakfastAvg
FROM day_Sales_total
```

b)

```
SELECT date, Day_Name_of_week
     , AVG(SalesItems_Breakfast) BreakfastAvg
FROM day_Sales_total
GROUP BY date, Day_Name_of_week
```

c) see @Serg's answer

I believe alternative b) is the way to go here

Answer (score 4):

Probably you need

```
SELECT date,
        Day_Name_of_week,
        AVG(AVG(SalesItems_Breakfast)) OVER (PARTITION BY Day_Name_of_week) AS BreakfastAvg
    FROM day_Sales_total
    GROUP BY date, day_Sales_total.Day_Name_of_week
```

So that `GROUP`ed `BY date, day_Sales_total.Day_Name_of_week` average `AVG(SalesItems_Breakfast)` is partitoned by `Day_Name_of_week` and new `AVG()` is calculated.

Comment: Or `AVG(SUM(SalesItems_Breakfast))` or `AVG(MIN(SalesItems_Breakfast))`, ... or some other combination.